# Run a Cypress before() only before a certain subset of files

Tags: javascript, cypress

There is a folder in my Cypress `integration` folder that contains a bunch of tests spread out through multiple files. I want to run a `before()` statement before all of these tests, and an `after()` when they are all done. However, I can't use the general support file, because I don't want the `before()` and `after()` to be run before and after all tests in the project.

What is the easiest way to do this? I was hoping for some sort of of support file. Just like `cypress/support/index.js` runs before all tests in the project, I was hoping to maybe make a file that runs before a certain subset of tests contained in a folder in `integration`.

Comment: The global Cypress object has a property `Cypress.spec.name` which should contain the full path of the spec, so you could parse that ***within the before()*** and conditionally run the before code. Note, this property is valid when invoking `cypress run` and also running individual specs from the GUI (`cypress open`), but not when hitting the 'all tests' button from the GUI - in this case Cypress.spec.name is assigned '_all'.

Comment: If you give some code and folder structure, can post a specific example.